# Algorithm to exteact words from an string

Tags: algorithm, cobol

I’m woking with TELON/COBOL atm, i need an algorithm to extract words from a strings. 
Tried searching but couldn’t find anything similar.

Anyway the algorithm needs to extract the words, and ignore spaces; here is what i have so far (ive put in comments for people who aren’t familiar with e syntax)

WS-STRING is the input string

WS-WORD-LEN is the length of the word to be extracted

WS-LST-WORD-P is the starting position of the current word to be extracted (within the sting)

WS-SUB1 is the loop index

```
PERFORM TEST BEFORE                                      
VARYING WS-SUB1 FROM 1 BY 1                              
  UNTIL WS-SUB1 > WS-STRING-LEN //loop for each char in the string, add 1 to WS-SUB1 in each itiaration                         
    EVALUATE TRUE                                        
       WHEN WS-STRING(WS-SUB1:1) = SPACES  //if the current char is a space              
            MOVE WS-SUB1              TO WS-SUB1-FRD     
            ADD  1                    TO WS-SUB1-FRD     
            IF WS-STRING(WS-SUB1-FRD:1) = SPACES  //Checks to see if the next char is a space       
                ADD  1                TO WS-LST-WORD-P   
            ELSE                                         
                MOVE WS-STRING(WS-LST-WORD-P:WS-WORD-LEN) //Substing "WS-WORD-LEN" many char from "WS-STRING" starting at "WS-LST-WORD-P" into "WS-WORD-OUT" 
                                      TO WS-WORD-OUT     
                ADD  1                TO WS-COUNT(2)     
                PERFORM Z-400-OUTPUT-WORD  //This outputs "WS-WORD-OUT" to a file.              
                MOVE WS-SUB1          TO WS-LST-WORD-P   
                MOVE 1                TO WS-WORD-LEN   
            END-IF                                     
       WHEN OTHER                                      
            ADD  1                    TO WS-WORD-LEN   
    END-EVALUATE                                       
END-PERFORM                                            
MOVE 1                               TO WS-LST-WORD-P
```

This algorithm sort of works, but some of the output is spliced at the beginning/end. 
so any ideas on whats wrong here or suggest something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at UNSTRING ?  It would seem tailor-made for your situation.

```
MOVE 1 TO WS-SUB1
PERFORM UNTIL WS-SUB1 >= LENGTH OF WS-STRING
  UNSTRING WS-STRING DELIMITED SPACE
    INTO WS-WORD-OUT COUNT IN WS-WORD-LEN
    POINTER WS-SUB1
  END-UNSTRING
  ADD 1 TO WS-COUNT(2)
  PERFORM Z-400-OUTPUT-WORD
  ADD WS-WORD-LEN TO WS-SUB1
END-PERFORM
```

Nota bene: the code is just freehand, uncompiled and untested.

Answer (score 2):

@cschneid
 is right. UNSTRING is the way to go. Use DELIMITED BY ALL SPACES if you want multiple spaces to be treated as a single delimiter. There's an example at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/c0925395564.htm.

If you need to put it all back together later you can use the STRING verb to do that. I recommend that you also use an ON OVERFLOW clause to catch things like a word that is too long to fit into the target variable. It happens.